# ionic accidentally unsubscribe event when unload with menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

**Background**
A ionic app with menu and two pages (`Home` and `list`).

`Home` page subscribes an event on `ionViewWillEnter`
and unsubscribes it on `ionViewWillUnload`.

**Correct situation:**
Start app with `Home` and the event subscribed.
If toggle menu and click `List` from `Home`, the event unsubscribed.
Re-enter `Home` and the event subscribed.

**Wrong situation:**
App started with `Home` and event subscribed.
Toggle menu > click `Home` >
Console:
event subscribed
event unsubscribed

Result is the event unsubscribed on `Home` page.

**Desire situation**
Enter `Home`(from other page / re-enter from menu) > subscribe event once.
Leave `Home`(to other page / re-load same page from menu) unsubscribe event once.

**Playground**
[ionic-menu](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-menu-life-cycle)

I expect the enter and unload come with pair.
If re-entering same page, unload should runs before enter.
However, it's not the case.
Please suggest a way for proper (un)subscribe event in ionic
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage /*implements OnInit, OnDestroy*/ {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public events: Events) {}




  ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log("ion enter info subscribed");
    this.events.subscribe('get-info');
    this.events.subscribe("value",(data) => {
      console.log("ion enter info subscribed");
    this.events.subscribe('get-info');
    });
  }

  ionViewWillUnload() {
    console.log("ion unload info unsubscribed");
     this.events.publish('value',true)
    this.events.unsubscribe('get-info');

  }
```

Comment: If switch from `Home` to `List`, event subscribed again which is not desired as `Home` page not active. For coding view, it is because publishing `value` causes subscription again.
Also, for re-entering `Home`, subscription duplicated as many times as you re-enter the page.
May you share idea behind?